# Subspace Criterion

Tags: vector-spaces

Given V = {f :R→R | f(x)=a+bx+cx^2 where a, b, c ∈ R} and
W = {f :R→R | f(x)=α+βx^2 where α, β ∈ R}.

How do I prove that the subset W ⊆ V is a subset of vector subspace V?
I know that W needs to be closed under vector addition and closed under scalar multiplication.

Does that mean, say for closure under vector addition, I need to construct matrix (x  f(x))^T and let u and v be members of vector subspace W with a certain value of x and add u+v and check whether u+v fits the form α+βx^2?

Comment: Looks you are overthinking it.  To prove it is closed under addition note that $(\alpha +\beta x^2)+(\gamma +\delta x^2)= (\alpha +\gamma)+(\beta +\delta)x^2$ and similarly for scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u,v \in W$ and check out that 
$\lambda u + \mu v \in W$. This is the most simple way to show it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\lambda u - \mu v \in W$?

Answer (score -2):

For a slightly different approach,  you can check that $W$ is both a subset of $V$ and that it is a vector space.

It's a subset by letting $b=0$.

It's also clear that $W$ is the image of $\mathcal R^2$, under the application $(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow (\alpha, 0,\beta)$. Thus a vector space.

---

Or, note that $W=\text{span}\{1,x^2\}\subset\text{span}\{1,x,x^2\}=V$.

Comment: It makes no sense to claim that $W$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ until you have proved that it is a vector space.

Comment: Maybe I could have been a little more cautious.   But you are splitting hairs.  @JoséCarlosSantos